# Custom View Strategy in zend framework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I create a Custom Renderer and edit the Admin\config\module.config.php

```
'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
                View\Renderer::class => function($serviceManager){
                     return new Renderer('ISO-8859-1');
                },
                'MyStrategy' => function($serviceManager){
                     $render = $serviceManager->get(View\Renderer::class);
                     $strategy = new PhpRendererStrategy($render);
                     return $strategy;
                },

 'view_manager' => [
    ...
    'strategies' => [
        'ViewJsonStrategy',
        'MyStrategy'
    ]
```

but the follow error occurs:

```
  Fatal error: Uncaught Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException: Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "error/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file in C:\xampp\htdocs\zf3dashboard\vendor\zendframework\zend-view\src\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php:498
```

Comment: Spent 2 days on the same problem. Can you show your code ?

Comment: Not in comment, edit the question ;)

Comment: the stackoverflow limit size of code

Comment: You're going to have to show more of what you tried and where stuff goes wrong. Also, keep in mind that you should not use the servicemanager anymore in the way that you are. Create a separate class & factory, register them with the servicemanager in the config and map your strategy alias to a class. Also use the correct manager to provide what you need; of the top of my head you'll need to do `$container->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('PhpRenderer')` to get the renderer you're after. Do not instantiate (`new whatever()`) those classes with dependencies (e.g. `PhpRendererStrategy`).